# Coarse moduli space of compact polarized Fano Kaehler-Einstein manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $\mathcal X\to \mathcal S$, be a family of polarized
Kaehler manifolds with $\omega_s= Ric(\omega_s)$(i.e., fibers are Fano Kahler-Einstein manifolds). Then $dim Aut(X_s)=Const$.?

Is there any construction of the [coarse moduli space](https://www.aimath.org/WWN/modspacecurves/glossary/node5.html) of compact polarized
Fano Kaehler-Einstein manifolds?

Comment: Consider a Fano manifold $X$ such that ${\rm Aut}(X)$ is transitive on an open set $U\subset X$ and fixes a point $x_0\in X$. If you blow-up $x_0$ then all the automorphisms will lift to the blow-up, if you blow-up a point of $U$ youre potentially decreasing the dimension of the automorphism group. Take the family of $X$ blown-up at $p$ where $p$ moves from $U$ to $x_0$ and then find a new polarization in this family.

Comment: It is not true that the automorphism group stays constant in flat families. For an explicit example, look at the degenerations of Fano threefolds with a two dimensional torus action to toric Fano threefolds (the papers of Ilten-Süss). For the construction of the moduli space, see the work of Odaka and Li-Wang-Xu.

Comment: The general Fano threefold with Picard rank one, index one, and degree 22 has finite automorphism group, but the famous Mukai-Umemura Fano has positive dimensional automorphism group; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68096/mukai-umemura-3-fold-and-kaehler-einstein-metrics for instance.

Comment: In your case $s\to \text{ord Aut}(X_s)$ is upper semicontinuous.  Let $Aut^ω(\mathcal X/S)$ denote the space of automorphisms of $X_s$ which fix the Kähler classes $[ω_{X_s}]$ then if fibers admit Kähler -Einstein metric $Ric(\omega_s)=\omega_s$, then $\text{Aut}^ω(X/S)\to S $ is proper . The proof is as same as the paper of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389100

Comment: Let $X→S$ and $Y→S$ be families of compact complex manifolds whose fibers admit Kähler -Einstein metric with positive Ricci curvature; for every $s∈S$ let $X_s$ and $Y_s$ be isomorphic. Then $X→S$ and $Y→S$ are locally isomorphic. You can adopt the same proof of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389100 . see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01360031?LI=true and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589190?LI=true

Comment: Note that my previous comments are about the order of Automorphism group of fibers and is not directly related to your question, but it may be your interest.